# How To Run Android Emulation Without installing Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have installed flutter and created a new app.Now I need to run this application.I am using Visual Studio Code.

If i can create and develop flutter app using visual studio code so why should i install/need android studio.

Is there any way to run Android Emulation without installing Android Studio??

Note: Please excuse me if it is a stupid question.Android Studio is really a heavy software.If I need both of them (vs code and android studio),so what's the point of using vs code for code editing purpose?????

Thanks

Comment: It is possibile to run Android emulator without Android Studio. This is the [Google Official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator).

Comment: In my experience Android Studio isn't that heavy, but unfortunately the emulator and the packages for different setups is what's taking up space.

Comment: yes.I have not enough storage for that.that why i am looking for another way.

Comment: You can try Genymotion emulator

Answer (score 3):

Connect you mobile to your pc via USB and run the app on your mobile. Otherwise, use LDPlayer (emulator) instead of the android studio. It's very fast and highly customizable.